# c# decryption issue getting error Premature end of stream in PartialInputStream

Tags: c#, encryption

When trying to decrypt the file getting an error:

> Premature end of stream in PartialInputStream

I am using this library for encrypt decrypt:     https://github.com/mattosaurus/PgpCore#decryptfile

Code:

```
 try
            { 
                using (PGP pgp = new PGP())
                {
                    // Decrypt stream
                    using (FileStream inputFileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\test.zip.pgp", FileMode.Open))
                    using (Stream outputFileStream = File.Create(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\test.zip"))
                    using (Stream privateKeyStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\test Private.asc", FileMode.Open))
                        pgp.DecryptStream(inputFileStream, outputFileStream, privateKeyStream, "password");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string message = ex.Message;
                throw;
            }
```

Comment: Is the file encrypted first and then zipped, or the other way around?

Comment: to be honest given by  third party no idea

Comment: Probably zipped first. Zipping an encrypted file doesn't really work in terms of reducing its size.

Comment: What should be right flow 1) first encrypt and then zip  or 2) first zip and then encrypt

Comment: First zip. An encrypted file cannot be compressed with a general purpose compression algorithm.